# load APP in web Page with gWidgetsWWW2

Tags: r, extjs, gwidgets

I builded a GUI in `gWidgets2` and `gWidgets2Rgtk2`, but i want to share this GUI through of a Web page, i revised the package `gWidgetsWWW2`and `gWidgetsWWW2.rapache` but in the first the function `load_app` does not work, in the web page appear `Loading ExtJs` and with `gWidgetsWWW2.rapache` i dont find a function for load this app, somebody can help me?

```
 library(gWidgetsWWW2)
 load_app("myapp")
```

Comment: You might have meant `load_app("myapp.R")` (the filename must match exactly). That package doesn't get much attention these days. Basic stuff should still work, but the web technologies move pretty fast. I just checked that things run locally, but the apache set up may need tweaking.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, i am testing with this code: `gw_script <-  system.file("examples/hello-world.R", package="gWidgetsWWW2")
if(interactive()) load_app(gw_script, "HelloApp")`, but not work, in the browser appears _Loading ExtJS_

Comment: try `system.file("examples/ex-hello-world.R", package="gWidgetsWWW2")`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just pushed a fix to github to throw an error if the script does not exist and update the man page to point to the actual file.

Comment: Thanks for you Help!!!!....i try with `system.file("examples/ex-hello-world.R", package="gWidgetsWWW2")`but continues appearing in the IP Adress  _Loading ExtJS_

Comment: are you using ie? It can be a hassle to debug these things, but to give it a go you have to open something like firebug or its equivalent and see what the errors are.